# os.system not finding file that is really there

Tags: python, travis-ci

This happens in the python build:

```
#is it executable
print os.access("support/d8/d8", os.X_OK)
#is it there in the shell
os.system("test -f support/d8/d8 && echo \"found\" || echo \"not found\"")
```

and then:

```
#run it
os.system("support/d8/d8 --trace_exception with a bunch of files");
```

which outputs:

```
True
found
sh: 1: support/d8/d8: not found
```

I don't get it. It's there it's executable. Why is it not there when I start it.

- link to the travis build: https://travis-ci.org/albertjan/skulpt/builds
- and a link to the repository: https://github.com/albertjan/skulpt the build script is called `m`

Comment: What is the content of `support/d8/d8`? Note that `not found` can also mean that the interpreter or a library cannot be found or initialized.

Comment: it's a binary version of v8.

Comment: Why not use `subprocess.Popen`? It's must more reliable for this type of thing.

Comment: Can you run the program from your shell normally?

Comment: @nneonneo The bug occurs on [travis](https://travis-ci.org), which does not allow interactive shells (although one could rig one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running an x86_32 bit executable [`d8`](https://github.com/albertjan/skulpt/raw/master/support/d8/d8) (despite the [comment](https://github.com/albertjan/skulpt/blob/master/support/d8/skulpt_readme.txt), by the way). If the (Travis) system is x64, and/or does not have all of the x86_32 libraries

- `linux-gate.so.1`
- `libpthread.so.0`
- `libstdc++.so.6`
- `libm.so.6`
- `libgcc_s.so.1`
- `libc.so.6`

then the executable won't run, since the loader cannot find all required libraries. Build statically and/or for x64.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into building a static x64 v8.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:

```
 os.system("./support/d8/d8 --trace_exception with a bunch of files");
```

I had a similar issue, while executing the ./ is some how required.

Comment: -1 This is identical to `system('support/d8/d8 ...')` on any sane system. Most likely, you were executing a file without any slashes in it, which indeed has different semantics.

Comment: My bad, this is identical. Yes i tried the file without slash and concluded that this could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your file "support/d8/d8" has a non existent "bang line" then this error occurs

```
$ cat support/d8/d8
#!/usr/bin/thisdoesnotexist
echo "hello"
$ chmod 755 support/d8/d8 
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:20:15) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.system("support/d8/d8 --wer")
sh: 1: support/d8/d8: not found
32512
```

> > > 

Answer (score 0):

Adding the full file path seems to resolve the Error in Python 3.x.

Example: `/home/[your_username]/support/d8/d8`

You can use `pwd` to get the path of your current directory. Then add your filename and you're good to go.

Example: Let's say `pwd` outputs `/home/jakob/project` and your script is called `test.py` the line has to look like this: `os.system('/home/jakob/project/test.py')`.

PS: don't forget to `import os` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: If you encounter `sh: 1: home/jakob/project/test.py: Permission denied`, make sure that the script (in this case test.py) can be executed. On Linux: `sudo chmod +x test.py`

Comment: If you encounter `/home/jakob/project/test.py: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
`, you have to add `#!/usr/bin/python3` to the top of your test.py.